# How do I show the Ln and Col numbers in the Visual Basic editor?

Tags: vba

Most IDEs have a display that tells the user what line (Ln) and column (Col) position the cursor is currently located at. Is this function available in the Visual Basic Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Basic editor does have this functionality.

- The Ln and Col display is the last widget on the 'Standard' toolbar. You can right click on the menu bar or any toolbar and check the box next to 'Standard'.
- If the toolbar is enabled, but you cannot see the Ln/Col display then the tool bar placement has caused the VBE to truncate the toolbar; try moving your toolbars around.

Answer (score 1):

[As already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597827/1188513) that basic functionality is part of the [Standard] toolbar.

With [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an actively maintained, open-source VBE add-in project I manage), you get *much* more than that:

[image: Context selection status]

The [Rubberduck] toolbar dwarfs the VBE's line/column display, which only shows the *start* of the current selection. Rubberduck's context-sensitive toolbar displays:

- L1C1-style current selection for single-character selections
- L1C1-L1C1-style current selection for multiple-character selections

But also context-sensitive information about the selected *declaration*:

- The name of the type library it's located in;
- The fully-qualified module/member name;
- The type of declaration (whether it's a function, a property, etc.);
- The declared/return type, when applicable;
- If the declaration has a *docstring*, a `VB_Description` attribute, or a Rubberduck `@Description` annotation, that description appears in the toolbar;
- The number of references to that identifier *across the entire project*.

---

The latest/current pre-release/CI build apparently has a [bug that prevents the L1C1 selection from being displayed](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/3235). Will be fixed shortly. We're also working on fixing an annoying glitch that makes the reported number of references in the toolbar be off (clicking the button brings up the correct number of references in a *Search Results* toolwindow tab though). You may want to try v2.0.13 instead of the latest 2.1 prerelease/CI builds.